# Why function won't echo

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

This has to be simple enough but I cannot get my head around it. If I take out the query from the function the query echo's but if it's wrapped around a function it does not echo period.

Could someone explain to me what is happening exactly to cause it to not work?

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

function getFB($url)
{
    $fql = "SELECT url, share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='$url'";
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    return $data;
}
echo $getFB[0]['share_count'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You need to remove the dollar sign from the function

Second: I see that you're not passing a URL to the function thus it returns nothing

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

function getFB($url)
{
$fql = "SELECT url, share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='$url'";
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?    format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
$data = json_decode($json, true);
return $data;
}
$data = getFB($url);
echo $data[0]['share_count'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense again. Weird thing is that it just prints getFB wherever I echo it. I actually get this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' .